# Trigger uses class, writing test case for that class does not increase trigger coverage?

Tags: apex, trigger, unit-test

So I've got a trigger, T, for which i have class A which is where I stored all the "backend" logic.

The coverage for A is 100% but T has not seen any coverage increase and I'm wondering if this is normal behavior and if not how I go about doing so?

Comment: Without posting your trigger and testmethod; hard to say but most likely reason is that you are not doing all of the CRUD operations in the testmethod supported by trigger code (insert, update, delete, undelete)

Comment: So in the trigger I support both inserts and updates, and in the class, A, which the trigger calls I have inserts and updates as well. Does that mean my tester for A has to have both inserts and updates before the trigger will consider it to be tested even though A considers itself to be tested?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I THINK I figured it out - the trigger's code coverage describes the lines covered by the trigger only, not the components that it is calling (which themselves should have tests, also).

I was very confused because the number of lines of code in my trigger is the same as the number of components (components meaning methods defined within some class) so I didn't understand why the coverage wasn't going up.

Comment: if you use a trigger framework, the trigger itself is typically only 1 line of code - (see Trailhead](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/modules/apex_patterns_dsl/units/apex_patterns_dsl_learn_dl_principles). A simple CRUD operation on the trigger object suffices to cover